# How to access non-default Firestore database in AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to access another firestore database in my gcloud project. I can access the default one (default) fine, but I have one called 'development' that I can't access, and can't find any documentation online of how to access it.

When I got my initial firebase config it did not include a databaseURL, but i've added one to try and access the database but it doesn't work. This is how my config currently looks

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: <apiKey>,
  authDomain: <authDomain>,
  projectId: <projectId>,
  storageBucket: <storageBucket>,
  messagingSenderId: <messagingSenderId>,
  appId: <appId>,
  databaseURL: "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectId>/databases/development/",
  measurementId: <measurementId>,
  databaseId: "development",
};

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: firebaseConfig,
  databaseName: 'development',
};

// From looking at the docs, the default databaseURL would be "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectId>/databases/(default)/"
```

I am importing in my `app.module` like this

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig,),
AngularFirestoreModule
```

I've also tried

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig, {name: environment.databaseName}),
```

and

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig, environment.databaseName),
```

If I go to the databaseURL in a web browser, it comes up with

> Missing routing header. Please fill in the request header with format x-goog-request-params:project_id=pocketmechanic-2970f&database_id=development. Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-databases#access_a_named_database_with_a_client_library for more details.

Comment: I asked out lead engineer on AngularFire and he says this should be the same issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3450#issuecomment-1783617914

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: I've had to switch from the compat API to the modular API, I think thats the only way right now @OmarDulaimi

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm it works. But have you figured out a way to provideFirestore without loading the default database? (it implicitly does so)

Comment: Nevermind, I found out how.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, keeping in mind the need to refactor away from compat mode and use the modular syntax instead:

```
import { getApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from "@angular/fire/app";
import { initializeFirestore, provideFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(config)),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const app = getApp();
      const dbName = "db-name";
      const providedFirestore = initializeFirestore(app, {}, dbName);
      return providedFirestore;
    }),
  ]
})
```

Then in your services:

```
import { inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Firestore, getDocs } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  orderBy,
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class MyService {
  private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);

  getUsers() {
    return getDocs(
      query(
        collection(this.firestore, "Users"),
        where("some_id", "==", "id"),
        orderBy("created_at", "asc")
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This also can let you connect to multiple databases and inject them as needed.